# How to check user is authorized to view a page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, authorization, identityserver4

Authority - IdentityServer4

Xamarin.Forms - Shell & MVVM

API (protected by IdentityServer)

I want to send the users for Authentication (and authorization) when they hit my members page in my Xamarin.Forms app. Different roles will allow access to different pages on the app, but all users (authenticated or not) can see and use all navigation buttons.

Available Roles:

members

premiumMembers

I'm looking for something similar to the [Authorize(Roles="premiumMembers")] for a page in my Xamarin app. I'm using Shell and MVVM and so navigation is URL based and I guess the functionality would reside on the ViewModel.  I cannot find any indication that this exists, but seems so fundamental. If this does not exist, how do I make sure my page is only accessed by "premiumMembers"?

I can't see the way to do this using the MVVM and url navigation approach. If I was to implement this manually, eg Check if we have the identity token / claims etc, if not jump to IdentityServer to get them... where would this code run?  There must be a standard way to do this that I am missing.